# Kotlin Coroutines: Do we need to synchronize shared state?

Tags: kotlin

From the official guide and samples from web, I didn't see any mentions of **locking** or **synchronization**, or how safe is modifying a shared variable in multiple `launch` or `async` calls.

Comment: Kotlin [Continuation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/-continuation/index.html#continuation)  is just an interface that doesn't provide thread safe access, but you can implements your own `Continuation`s to make it thread-safely. see here: https://hyp.is/xSxsoopoEeegKEsi2kQGmg/github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/kotlin-coroutines-informal.md

Comment: Thanks! I'll read about it.

Comment: Not at all. if you open the link with chrome you will found I have highlighted the part what you care about.

Answer (score 10):

Coroutines bring a concurrent programming model that may result in simultaneously executed code. Just as you know it from thread-based libraries, you have to care about synchronization as noted in the docs:

> Coroutines can be executed concurrently using a multi-threaded dispatcher like the Dispatchers.Default. It presents all the usual concurrency problems. The main problem being synchronization of access to shared mutable state. Some solutions to this problem in the land of coroutines are similar to the solutions in the multi-threaded world, but others are unique.

With Kotlin **Coroutines** you can make use of acquainted strategies like using *thread-safe data structures*, *confining* execution to a single thread or using *locks* (e.g. Mutex).

Besides the common patterns, Kotlin coroutines encourage us to use a "**share by communication**" style. Concretely, an "actor" can be shared between coroutines. They can be used by coroutines, which may send/take messages to/from it. Also have a look at [Channels](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#channels).

Comment: I see, that's the hint I need at least. Thanks! I've read your page https://medium.com/@s1m0nw1/approaching-kotlin-coroutines-an-extensive-feature-concurrent-programming-in-kotlin-eaaa19b003d2

Comment: Then you should know already :) there's a whole section on shared state